# How to control the level of water in the toilet bowl?

Tags: toilet

Recently purchased a home and one of the toilet bowls has very little water in it, so when you do #2 it always hits the bowl and makes a mess...

How can you control/set the amount of water the bowl contains so I can raise/increase it a little bit?

Answer (score 4):

If the level in the tank is also extremely low it could be that the fill valve is adjusted way too low, thus not allowing enough water into the bowl from the refill tube.

The level in the bowl has nothing to do with the plumbing, it has to do with the design of the bowl. The track of the drain has an up "trap" and then down to the drain, so the water will only raise as high as the up trap then spill over into the drain.

Here is a visual:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is usually a small, flexible tube clipped to the overflow tube that adds water to the bowl while the tank is filling (marked as refill tube on Speedy Petey's diagram). If this comes loose or gets pinched, the water level in the bowl well be too low.

Answer (score 2):

Found this on [Kohler's website](https://www.kohler.com/en/support/help-and-faq/correct-low-water-level-in-toilet-bowl). It worked like a charm!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The water level in the bowl is down to the plumbing - specifically, the height before the drop into the foul drain. Generally, this isn't something that can be adjusted, but something inherent in the design of the bowl, in some cases to intentionally reduce the amount of water required to flush.